# How can I insert data from CSV files into mysql databse without missing rows.?

Tags: php, mysql, excel, csv

Using the code below, it was susccessful in inserting data from csv files.  However, it will not insert 100% of the data (row).. 1 or 2 records (row) data was missing...

Sample .. the number of row data is 20.. it will insert only 19 records.   Please help in correcting this codes  .. Thank you

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/tmp/Excelfile.csv'
INTO TABLE tablecovdata
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
IGNORE 0 ROWS;
```

Comment: Is the last line Terminated by `\n` ?

Comment: Yes, it was terminated by \n

Comment: I cannot replicate this observation

Comment: It would be good if you can show us a sample of your CSV file. I dont understand what `IGNORE 0 ROWS` is good for. The documentation says: `The IGNORE number LINES option can be used to ignore lines at the start of the file. For example, you can use IGNORE 1 LINES to skip an initial header line containing column names ` Try remove this line, more info here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html AND also try: `LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' ` instead of: `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' `